# Dynamically populate project drop down data based on client drop down choice data. But edit form show exception/error in symfony 5

Tags: symfony

I want to "Dynamically populate project drop down data based on client drop down choice data" in symfony 5. New page work properly, but when change client drop down value from edit page then ajax called and show this exception/error: "Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path "buildingPosition"."

Form Code:

```
class EnquiryType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('client', EntityType::class, [
            // looks for choices from this entity
            'class' => Client::class,

            // uses the User.username property as the visible option string
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'placeholder' => 'Select a Client...',
           // 'label' => 'Contact Person Designation',
            // used to render a select box, check boxes or radios
            // 'multiple' => true,
            // 'expanded' => true,
            ])

            ->add('buildingPosition', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control'],

                ])
             ->add('offerSubmissionDate', DateType::class, [
                 'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control'],
                 'widget' => 'single_text',
                 'empty_data' => null,


                 ])


            ->add('probability', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices'  => [
                'P1' => 'P1',
                'P2' => 'P2',
                'P3' => 'P3',
              ],
              'placeholder' => 'Select a Probability...',

           ])
            ->add('notes', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control'],
                 ])

           ;

            // Start Project data populate dynamically based on the value in the "client" field
            $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Client $client = null) {
                $projects = null === $client ? [] : $client->getProjects();

                $form->add('project', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => 'App\Entity\Project',
                    'placeholder' => '',
                    'choices' => $projects,
                ]);
            };

            $builder->addEventListener(
                FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
                function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                    // this would be your entity, i.e. Enquiry
                    $data = $event->getData();

                    $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getClient());
                }
            );

            $builder->get('client')->addEventListener(
                FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
                function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                    // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
                    // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
                    $client = $event->getForm()->getData();

                    // since we've added the listener to the child, we'll have to pass on
                    // the parent to the callback functions!
                    $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $client);
                }
            );

            // End Project data populate dynamically based on the value in the "client" field

    }
```

Controller Code:

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id): Response
    {
        $enquiry = new Enquiry();

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $enquiry = $entityManager->getRepository(Enquiry::class)->find($id);


        $form = $this->createForm(EnquiryType::class, $enquiry);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {


            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            $this->addFlash('notice', 'Enquiry updated successfully!');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('enquiry_index');
        }

        return $this->render('enquiry/edit.html.twig', [
            'enquiry' => $enquiry,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

Twig/View Code:

```
  {{ form_start(form) }}
              {{ form_row(form.client, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }} 
              {{ form_row(form.project, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }} 
              {{ form_row(form.buildingPosition) }}
              {{ form_row(form.offerSubmissionDate) }}
              {{ form_row(form.probability, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
              {{ form_row(form.notes) }}

      {{form_row(row)}}
```

JavaScript Code:

```
var $client = $('#enquiry_client');
// When sport gets selected ...
$client.change(function() {

  // ... retrieve the corresponding form.
  var $form = $(this).closest('form');

  // Simulate form data, but only include the selected sport value.
  var data = {};
  data[$client.attr('name')] = $client.val();
  // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
  $.ajax({
    url : $form.attr('action'),
    type: "POST",
    data : data,
    success: function(html) {

      // Replace current position field ...
      $('#enquiry_project').replaceWith(
        // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
        $(html).find('#enquiry_project')
      );
      // Position field now displays the appropriate positions.
    }
  });
});
```

Please help me.....

Comment: Can you detail what action is in  $form.attr('action') and provide the action code?

Comment: If you are submitting to the `edit` action, your form expects the whole form to be submitted, but you are submitting only one field. You should create a separate function for your javascript call that only accepts the `client` field and returns desired data.

Comment: My Problem is when changed Client dropdown value  from edit page by ajax call then  Project dropdown value not populated. When changed Client dropdown value by ajax then show ajax error/exception  is " Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path "buildingPosition " ". Dynamically populated Project dropdown value based on Client dropdown choice value  working properly  new page, but edit page not workinng properly.